# Replace character in std::string with hex value

Tags: c++, string, replace, hex

I am trying to replace a number/hex value in a `std::string` using `std::replace` but when I try and do `fileBuf.replace(0x10, 1, "0x44");` it just expands the string with an ASCII "0x44" instead of replacing the 1 character at position `0x10` with the value `0x44`. Is there a proper way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `\x` escape sequence to represent hexadecimal characters. Moreover, since you're replacing just one character, you could use character literals rather than string literals:

```
fileBuf.replace(0x10, 1, '\x44');
```

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea that escape sequence even existed. Will accept when s.o. lets me